# FormattedTime component throwing error when mounted in unit test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-intl

I am working on implementing a unit test for a custom React hook that utilizes the `react-intl` component `FormattedTime`.  Unfortunately, I am having trouble getting past the following error when mounted:

> [Error: FormattedTime(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.]

The portion of the hook that is using FormattedTime:

```
{ timeIncrements.map((time, key) => (
  <DropdownItem value={ format(convertTime(time, date), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:'00'") } key={ key }>
    <FormattedTime
      value={ convertTime(time, date) }
      timeZone={ timezone }
      timeZoneName='short'
      hour='numeric'
      minute='numeric'
      hour12={ true }
    />
  </DropdownItem>
)) }
```

I have confirmed that the `convertTime` function is returning a value to pass to the component.

There isn't much to the unit test yet, but here it is:

```
it('mounts component', () => {
  const Component = injectIntl(Settings);
  const wrapper = mount(<Component />);

  expect(wrapper.find(Schedule)).toHaveLength(1);

  wrapper.unmount();
});
```

**Is there a way to spyOn/mock that `FormattedTime` component?**  I have done similar spyOn for `FormattedMessage` errors, but can't seem to find a way to implement similar for `FormattedTime`.  I think this will be an easy question for someone, but it is giving me fits so asking for help.

---

Update based on answer from @diedu...here is the output from `wrapper.debug()`:

```
<IntlProvider locale="en-US" messages={{...}} formats={{...}} timeZone={[undefined]} textComponent={[symbol]} defaultLocale="en" defaultFormats={{...}} onError={[Function: mockConstructor] { _isMockFunction: true, getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)], mock: Object [Object: null prototype] { calls: [], instances: [], invocationCallOrder: [], results: [] }, mockClear: [Function (anonymous)], mockReset: [Function (anonymous)], mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)], mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)], mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)], mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)], mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)], mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)], mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)], mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)], mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)], mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)], mockName: [Function (anonymous)], getMockName: [Function (anonymous)] }} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-intl` needs an I18n Context to work, you need to wrap the component you're testing with all the providers 3rd party libs need when mounting.

```
  it("mounts component", () => {
    const Component = injectIntl(Settings);
    const wrapper = mount(
      <IntlProvider locale={usersLocale} messages={translationsForUsersLocale}>
        <Component />
      </IntlProvider>
    );

    expect(wrapper.find(Schedule)).toHaveLength(1);

    wrapper.unmount();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The errors seem to disappear, but the expected find fails because it is now just the `IntlProvider` being mounted.  Thus, the test does not do what was intended.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @cfnerd check what is being rendered with `console.log(wrapper.debug())` to see if the Schedule component is really present

Comment: it's just the provider.  `console.log     <IntlProvider locale="en-US" `

Comment: @cfnerd really? but you're still using `mount` right? could you add the full output of `debug()` to the question?

Comment: It's possible that I need to test for different things when this provider is used.  By that, I mean that rather than checking for the component I can update the props and see if the actual actions are working as expected if the state value has updated.

Comment: @cfnerd, that output doesn't seem right. It's like if you weren't rendering anything in the provider. I'll need to set up a reproducible example to check, will do it later when I get a chance

Comment: Hey, @cfnerd, do you still need help with this? I see you accepted my answer

Comment: it's close enough.  i likely just need to adjust a few things.